# Active Scripting on the server side

Tags: c++, windows, scripting, activex

I am considering writing a NT service. The service will need scripting capabilities. Users can write some VBScript/JScript code and feed the server.

I also want the script be able to debug in Microsoft Script Debugger.

The service will behave in a similar way as IIS with classic ASP. It gets input from somewhere else. When it get input, it runs the script user provided.

Right now all information I can found is MFC related. If I do not use MFC, how difficult to write such a program? Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it but... some ideas

- consider using Powershell.   Search for "remote runspace" or look into [Hanselman's old article on it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScriptBlockAndRunspaceRemotingInPowerShell.aspx).  I'm not sure if this made it into Powershell v2, but there was some talk of it.
- investigate [PowershellTunnel](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellTunnel).
- look into  [.NET 4.0 and the DLR](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/DotNet4pt010102009064108AM/DotNet4pt0.aspx).
- [an article on using cscript.exe to host dynamically entered vbscript](http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/windows_scripting_creating_a_vbscript_shell)
- [similar interactive JavaScript shell](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/a-jscript-interactive-interpreter-shell-for-the-windows-script-host/) - you'd have to grab hold of stdin/stdout differently